# Count the number of times a value appears in a column and return that value to a different worksheet

Tags: vba

I would like to consolidate my current script to be more dynamic. I am trying to count the number of times a unique value appears in a column. I want it to be dynamic regardless of the amount of unique items. There could be 5,6 or however many different values in this column. I would like to find out how many times each unique value is in the column and return it to a different worksheet.

Here is how I complete this as of now.

```
Dim Total As Range
Set Total = ws.Range("B2")
Total.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Column("A"), "Apple")
```

But this is a script adapted to fit a fixed, not dynamic, set of a data. I would like to look for any unique value and count how many times it appears. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: Did you mean statistics of only Column A, or all columns used?

Comment: Did you at least try my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895049/11167163) or an other one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try code below. I think it works good. I filled up only column "A". If you have more data then change rng or 1 in dict(arr(i, **1**)) to correct column in range.

Add References - Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Sub count_unique()
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rng.Value

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) '1 means rows, 2 - columns
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = 0
    Next

    arr = dict.keys()

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        count_key = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, arr(i))
        Debug.Print arr(i), count_key
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `dictionary` As I Said in my answer but your code will **be less efficient** due to the browse of the same array 2 times ... So this can be slow if there is a huge dictionary

Comment: I didn't see your answer. Sorry. Yeah i agree but for huge dict it's better to use db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
Sub CountValues()
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lMaxRow As Long, lTemp As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'assumes that data is in first column of first worksheet.
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2) 'change this to the desired output worksheet.
'find last used row in column A.
    lMaxRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'copy original data in a temporary column that has no data (eg.:AA).
    ws1.Range("A1:A" & lMaxRow).Copy ws1.Range("AA1:AA" & lMaxRow)
'remove duplicates from the temporary column.
    ws1.Range("AA1:AA" & lMaxRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
'count unique values in temporary column AA.
    lTemp = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row
'count each unique value.
    For i = 1 To lTemp
        ws2.Range("A" & i) = ws1.Range("AA" & i)
        ws2.Range("B" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws1.Range("A1:A" & lMaxRow), ws1.Range("AA" & i))
    Next
'clear temporary column
    ws1.Range("AA1:AA" & lMaxRow).ClearContents
'at this point this code outputs in worksheet2 the unique values in column A and the count in column B.
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```